# Run cabal executable with different paths containing data-files

Tags: haskell, deployment, cabal

I have an executable built by cabal that uses `data-files:` feature. I need to run it under different configs (for example `cd /opt/my-app/config2 && ./my-app` or `PREFIX=/opt/my-app/config2 ./my-app`). It currently looks into a fixed path.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code)?

Comment: What exactly does "run it under different configs" mean?